# Angular Jest test async code is not async

Tags: angular

Here is a method on a component

```
public onClick(event: any): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.service.getSomething().subscribe( ("foo") => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
}
```

Then the test

```
it('test', fakeAsync(()=> {
  component.onClick()
  expect(component.isLoading).toBe(true);
  tick()
  expect(component.isLoading).toBe(false);
}))
```

it fails saying that isLoading is false. Debugging shows that the code gets executed in order, this means that the control is returned **after** the code **inside** the subscribe is executed.

Comment: Are you certain that it makes it inside of the `subscribe` block? Are you mocking `getSomething` to return an observable before calling `component.onClick()` in the test?

Comment: Yes. Actually I think I find the answer. It seems like `Observable.of` is not `async` per se. Playing around with `asyncScheduler` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `Observable.of` is not async per se. You must make it async